# Filtering data retrieved based on checkbox

Tags: android, web-services, filter

I'm facing some problem with filtering the data I retrieved from the web server. From what I know, I'm able to use text input and filter the data retrieved. Like for example, if the input is "family", then the link will change from

http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&location=singapore&category=

to

http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&location=singapore&category=family

May I know what is the code for me to insert the input I have gotten from the user and insert it into the url?